# Async load multiple JS from data attribute is it normal?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous

**I put the several JS files inside attribute of my div and then take them do "append head"**

```
<div id='asyncjs' data-asyncjs='
<script src="/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="/file1.js"></script>
<script src="/file2.js"></script>
<script src="/file3.js"></script>
<script src="/file4.js"></script>
'></div>

<script>
var src = document.getElementById("asyncjs");
var magic = src.getAttribute("data-asyncjs");
$('head').append(magic);
</script>
```

**It works. But is it normal for use?**

P.S.
Also I tried to use

```
document.head.appendChild(magic)
```

instead

```
$('head').append(magic);
```

But this is an error... Why?

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'.

Comment: It work, but you have an error ?! So it doesn't work.. In all case even if you browser handle that, put HTML on attribute isn't a right thing to do

Comment: У меня все действительно работает. В современных браузерах.

Comment: That's all really works. In modern browsers.

Answer (score 0):

> It works. But is it normal for use?

Doesn't seem very normal, and it's not valid to have `<` symbols in an attribute. If you need to asynchronously load scripts, why not use the `async` attribute on actual `<script>` tags?

```
<script src="/jquery.js" async="async"></script>
<script src="/file1.js" async="async"></script>
<script src="/file2.js" async="async"></script>
<script src="/file3.js" async="async"></script>
<script src="/file4.js" async="async"></script>
```

> But this is an error... Why?

Because you can't pass a string into `.appendChild()`. It only accepts nodes. If you must use this approach, you can create a `div`, set its `innerHTML`, and then append that to the document head.

```
var scriptDiv = document.createElement('div');
scriptDiv.innerHTML = magic;
document.head.appendChild(scriptDiv);
```

Comment: > why not use the async attribute on actual <script> tags?

Comment: I can not. The reason is that the array with a list of JS I get through backend cms -  I will not be  edit the source code of cms

Comment: @TravisCat Ok, well you didn't explain any of that in your question, so it's very hard to provide you a worthwhile answer on that matter. But I have explained why you were getting an error and how to get around it with vanilla JS.